# How to replace the empty values "" on same index from another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have to string arrays as follows both arrays size (count) same but values of both arrays are not the same.

```
arrayAlpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"] 
          
arrayNume  = ["", "", "3", "4", "", "6", "", "", "9", ""] 

mixArray = [String]()
```

I want another Array called MixUPCArray which will have the values of both arrays as the same as the current index. First, it will load the UPC values for the positions of an empty string "" in the chosenProductUPCArray then keep the chosenProductUPCArray arrays string values on the as position as it is.

so the output will be like this

```
MixArray   = ["a", "b", "3", "4", "e", "6", "g", "h", "9", "j"]
```

Keep in mind that ArrayAlpha and ArrayNume size is always the same and just some empty values are coming in ArrayNume but ArrayAlpha always contains the full values

Please write the best solution for this in swift MixArray also same size as the both arrays.

Comment: what school project is this from?

Comment: @workingdog I have a similar situation to solve in my project but this is just a self construct coding quiz to get some ideas. If you know please write a solution in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can zimply zip both arrays and map the resulting tuples. If the second element is empty return the first otherwise return the second:

```
let arrayAlpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
let arrayNume  = ["", "", "3", "4", "", "6", "", "", "9", ""]

let mixArray = zip(arrayAlpha, arrayNume).map { $1.isEmpty ? $0 : $1 }

print(mixArray)  // ["a", "b", "3", "4", "e", "6", "g", "h", "9", "j"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo Dabus. This one is new thing today I learn and help full for me.